# Is strong signed the same as strong named for an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a difference between a `strongly signed` and a `strongly named` .NET assembly?

If yes, how can I determine whether a assembly is strongly signed using Visual Studio (I know how check if it is strongly named)?

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

Background: In the book `WiX: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML` is says you need to have a *strongly-signed assembly* in order to install it into the GAC.

So what do I need to install an assembly in the GAC: strong name or signed assembly?

Comment: There is no `strongly signed`. There is only `signed` and `strongly named`.

Comment: @Allostad: So this seems to be a mistake in my reference (see edit)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signing an assembly makes it strongly named. See [Strong-named assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx).

To be able to instal it into the GAC, an assembly needs to be strong-named and, therefor, signed.

Comment: So if I understood it correctly: signing an assembly is part of making it strong named. If an assembly is strong named it has to be signed. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep. Actually, signing an assembly is all you need to do to make it strong named.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `strongly signed`. There is only `signed` and `strongly named`.

In order to find out if it is signed on not (*i.e.* strongly named or not), open it with **ildasm.exe** and click manifest on the tree and look for public key token. if there is one then it is signed.

For example, opening `castle.core.dll` shows this (proving it is strongly named):

```
 .publickey = (00 24 00 00 04 80 00 00 94 00 00 00 06 02 00 00   // .$..............
                00 24 00 00 52 53 41 31 00 04 00 00 01 00 01 00   // .$..RSA1........
                77 F5 E8 70 30 DA DC CC E6 90 2C 6A DA B7 A9 87   // w..p0.....,j....
                BD 69 CB 58 19 99 15 31 F5 60 78 5E AC FC 89 B6   // .i.X...1.`x^....
                FC DD F6 BB 2A 00 74 3A 71 94 E4 54 C0 27 34 47   // ....*.t:q..T.'4G
                FC 6E EC 36 47 4B A8 E5 A3 82 31 47 D2 14 29 8E   // .n.6GK....1G..).
                4F 9A 63 1B 1A FE E1 A5 1F FE AE 46 72 D4 98 F1   // O.c........Fr...
                4B 00 0E 3D 32 14 53 CD D8 AC 06 4D E7 E1 CF 4D   // K..=2.S....M...M
                22 2B 7E 81 F5 4D 4F D4 67 25 37 0D 70 2A 05 B4   // "+~..MO.g%7.p*..
                87 38 CC 29 D0 92 28 F1 AA 72 2A E1 A9 CA 02 FB ) // .8.)..(..r*.....
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 2:5:1:0
}
```